# Strange issues with expanding and collapsing list elements in a Wordpress generated form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu

I'm hoping someone might be able to show me
a) what is causing the current issues
b) an altogether more elegant solution
for the following problem:

I am extracting all the pages out of a Wordpress blog and the idea is to create a menu where sub navigation expands and contracts as the user interacts.

**The nested menu markup is essentially as follows:**

```
<nav id="projects">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="page_item page-item-249">
        <a href="...">Selected projects</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-298"><a href="..." >Level 2</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-263"><a href="..." >Level 2</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-212"><a href="..." >Level 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-238">
        <a href="...">Archive</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-33">
                <a href="...">Level 2</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="page_item page-item-46"><a href="...">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-48"><a href="...">Level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-35">
                <a href="...">Level 2</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="page_item page-item-52"><a href="...">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-57"><a href="...">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-59"><a href="...">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-61"><a href="...">Level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The jQuery is as follows :**

```
$(".page_item a").click( function(){

    /* Set vars */
    var $this = $(this);
    var isActive = false;
    var hasSublinks = false;
    var nextLevel = $(this).next("ul");

    if ( $this.next().html() !== null ) {hasSublinks = true;}
    if ( $this.hasClass('active') ) {isActive = true;}

    if ( !hasSublinks ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        /* I have sub links... */
        if (!isActive) {
            /* I am not active */
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(".children").slideUp();

            $(this).next("ul").slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('active');

        } else {
            $(nextLevel).slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('active');

        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

When I click on 'Archive', it expands its child list as expected. However, when I click on a link here, I expect it to slide down and reveal the next level (Level 3) but it has the opposite effect of sliding *up* to go back to where I started from.

I've spent a lot of time in the console, on Wordpress Codex trying to see what might be the issue, particularly challenging for me is that this code was working before (or seemed to). I'm aware that the code isn't the cleanest so I'm really hoping can show me where I'm going wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have the class active anywhere, so when you are doing this :

```
  if ( $this.hasClass('active') ) {isActive = true;}
```

It set is Active to false

So you go in this part of code :

```
if (!isActive) {
        /* I am not active */
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(".children").slideUp();
```

There is clearly a problem with your logic, try fixing it, i'll give you a hint if you find nothing

Comment: Have you found/Try something here ?